# Deploying Rails Apps to VPS using Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vps

So I have been working on getting my VPS setup with no progress in a while so I figured I'd swallow my pride and ask here.

I have followed the following tutorials:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/

got to the end of the tutorial and only have the Welcome to nginx! display

It is really strange because everywhere tells me that I should be pointed to my new deployed rails app. Is this something to do with my nginx config file?

PS. i tried to find a similar problem to mine before but if this is a duplicate I do appologize.

Thanks in advance

Here is my nginx.conf file: Im looking at it right now and I know its a mess

```
worker_processes 3;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.18;
    passenger_ruby /bradbury/public;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile    on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /rails_app/myapplication/public;

        passenger_enabled on;

        error_page  500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) about deploying to a VPS . But , as you've said , you have got some things done . Just post your nginx.conf . We have to start from somewhere ...

Comment: I guess you can connect to the VPS by ssh. Try to navigate to your /rails_app/myapplication/public and check for index.html (we should be sure that your app is correctly checked out ).

Comment: yup just checked it and the index.html file is there